# Scratched capacitors at the top. Should I care?

Tags: capacitor, damage

I've ordered a couple of big capacitors and one of them (the one on the right) seems to have been repeatedly hammered by the other's leads during transportation. So much so that it has some considerable marks at the top (see picture). Should I be concerned about the capacitor performance or safety given those scratches?

[image: Scratched capacitor]

Comment: Probably fine... Your suppliers seem to not be of good quality if they just shipped them loose like that.

Comment: Are they going in a ventilator or an audio amplifier? If you need ultra high reliability then I would query the supplier, for a hobby project I'd probably use them.

Comment: @MadHatter that was DigiKey...

Comment: I am blown away that digi-key shipped you something like that, usually all my capacitors from them are in like bubble wrap individually once like to start getting that big.